# массив записать в csv Nodejs Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть два массива

```
massive.name = { name1, name2, name3 ...}
massive.price = { price1, price2, price3 ...}
```

Каждому massive.name[i], соотвествует massive.price[i].
Как мне эти данные записать в csv файл где первый столбец будет name а второй price

```
name1 price1
name2 price2
```

Думаю, что надо это реализовывать через fs.writeFileSync()
У меня ток в одну строку получается), и только один из двух данных либо name либо price

....
javascript nodejs

Comment: И где же ваш код?

Comment: ам , ну вот fs.writeFileSync('./app/data.csv', massive.name);

Answer (score 2):

```
let content = "";
/любой цикл, чтобы пройтись по обоим объектам/ {
 content += massive.name[i] + "," + massive.price[i] + "\n" 
// запятая разделяет на столбцы, \n - новая строка.
}
fs.writeFile("./app/data.csv", content, { encoding: "binary" })
```